# Understanding EJB3/JPA container-level transactions and isolation level

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Consider this simplified view of some code with which I'm working:

```
@Stateless(...)
@Remote(...)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class FirstEjbType {

   @EJB(...)
   private SecondEjbType secondEjb;
   @EJB(...)
   private ThirdEjbType thirdEjb;

   public void doSomething() {
      secondEjb.doSomething();  // WRITES SOMETHING TO THE DATABASE
      thirdEjb.doSomething();  // CAN'T SEE THAT SOMETHING IN THE DATABASE!
}
```

I've set the `TransactionAttribute` annotation to `MANDATORY` at the class-level.  I understand this to mean that all methods such as `doSomething()` must be invoked within a supplied transaction.  We are using container-managed transactions in this case.

The `TransactionAttribute` is not used at all in `SecondEjbType` or `ThirdEjbType`... neither at the class nor method level.  I understand this to mean that `secondEjb.doSomething()` and `thirdEjb.doSomething()` will both operate within the transaction supplied for `firstEjb.doSomething()`.

However, I'm seriously missing out on *something*!  As indicated by the code comments... `secondEjb` writes data to a database, and `thirdEjb` reads that data as part of its operation.  Since all of this is running within the same transaction, I would not expect there to be any issues with isolation levels.  **However, for whatever reason the `secondEjb` database write isn't visible to `thirdEjb`.**

I've turned tracing all the way up to the max, and there's apparently not an exception or error or rollback at issue... the initial write simply isn't visible to the subsequent read.  I don't claim to be the world's greatest guru in transaction management... have I missed something obvious, or is my conceptual understanding basically correct and the issue may lie elsewhere?

---

### UPDATE - Additional information requested by johnstok below:

- I am running in GlassFish
- I'm not sure what you mean by "non-standard flush mode", so I assume the answer is no.
- My persistence.xml file looks like this:

`<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">`
    `<persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="JTA">`
       `<jta-data-source>jdbc/datasource</jta-data-source>`
        `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`
        `<properties>`
            `<property name="toplink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>`
        `</properties>`
    `</persistence-unit>`
`</persistence>`

Comment: Ask yourself - "When does the commit occur?" Oh, and in conjunction with that "What is my transaction isolation level?"

Comment: I added details on flush modes below. What annotations are on the 2nd & 3rd EJBS? Can you try REQUIRED rather than MANDATORY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned a ton from all the answers here, and can't thank people enough.  However, I believe that my question has muddied the waters to a point where it might be better to start over with a different question.

It doesn't appear that jumping from one EJB to the next and back has anything to do with anything.  To simplify matters, I tried working with a test case completely isolated to one EJB.  I went into that `secondEjb.doSomething()` method, which persists an entity to the database.  At the end of the method, I added an `em.flush()`, and tried retrieving the entity again with a JPA query.

Even though I was ***still in the exact same method where the entity had just been persisted***, it was not visible to that subsequent query.  I've done [some additional research elsewhere](http://www.coderanch.com/t/90633/JBoss/EntityManager-flush-not-flushing), and it looks like this may simply be the normal mode of isolation for JPA in a transactional context.  One a transaction is started, additional queries within that transaction don't yet have visibility to uncommitted data.

If my summary of the linked CodeRanch discussion is accurate, then "yuck" on JPA!  :)  Either way, I've refactored the code to avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: I don't believe your summary of the coderanch thread is accurate. Uncommitted data **are** of course "visible" from subsequent queries within a transaction. Everything would get wrong if they weren't, nothing could work.

Comment: I agree... but nevertheless, I have uncommitted data not visible to subsequent queries *within the same method*.  To be fair though, the "write" operation in that method invokes a helper class which in turn invokes a DAO layer... so who knows what subtle detail may be tripping me up (the method's transaction *should* propagate downward to that helper class and DAO, since there are no Remote interfaces involved).  Short of posting a tarball of my entire codebase, this may just be a question beyond the scope appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Is this DAO using an EntityManager?? If yes, how is this EntityManager obtained (is it passed through from the EJB where it is injected to the DAO?)? If not, how is the database connection obtained? from the JTA datasource used by JPA? Too much details are missing IMO. But I still think your summary of the coderanch thread is inaccurate.

Comment: The DAO layer is using an EntityManager, which is obtained through EJB dependency injection.

Comment: Hmm... do you believe that CodeRanch thread is inaccurate, or that my summary of that thread is inaccurate.  If the latter, what do you read that thread as actually saying?

Comment: This part `(...) and it looks like this may simply be the normal mode of isolation for JPA in a transactional context. One a transaction is started, additional queries within that transaction don't yet have visibility to uncommitted data.` can't be true, at least not as a general statement. See section **3.6.2 Queries and FlushMode** of the spec. Regarding the thread on coderanch, I don't think there is anything to conclude from it.

Comment: Just to confirm what Pascal said: data committed in a transaction is visible in that transaction (I have clearly tested it). Besides, there could simply be a bug in your application server. Also, if you use any Caching (on JPA level), I would try to disable it.

Answer (score 15):

First thing to check is that bean two and three use `@PersistenceContext EntityManager` to get the EntityManager and **not** `@PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory` followed by a `createEntityManager()` call.

Second, check that the `DataSource` is actually setup to participate in JTA transactions (autoCommit or related properties should be off).

Lastly, a quick and dirty way to check your propagation is to call the `EntityManager.getDelegate()` method and check the resulting object is **the same** throughout the expected transaction scope.

Here's how things work under the covers....  The `EntityManager` injected into your bean when it is created is a fake, a simple facade.  When you attempt to use the EntityManager reference in a transaction, the container will actually go digging in the current transaction, find the *real* EntityManager that is stashed in the transaction scope and delegate your call to *that* EntityManager (if there is no EntityManager already in the transaction, the container will create one and add it).  This *real* object will be the value of `getDelegate()`.  If the value of `getDelegate()` is not the same (==) in `secondEjb.doSomething()` and in `thirdEjb.doSomething()` then you are not getting the expected propagation and each is talking to a different persistence context.

On a side note, beware that applying MANDATORY on the class actually only affects methods defined in that exact class, not in super classes.  If you do not specify an @TransactionAttribute on a super class, those methods use the default regardless of how subclasses maybe annotated.  I only mention that as it may have an impact on your understanding of your code.

Comment: +1 I always enjoy reading details about the behavior under the hood. Thanks.

Comment: great points, David. I sure have learnt something from this post.

Answer (score 13):

> I've set the TransactionAttribute annotation to MANDATORY at the class-level. I understand this to mean that all methods such as doSomething() must be invoked within a supplied transaction. We are using container-managed transactions in this case.

Using `MANDATORY` at the class level means that the container should throw an exception to the caller if there is no transaction in progress when any method of `FirstEjbType` is called.

Out of curiosity, who is initiating the transaction then? Is there a particular reason to not use the default `REQUIRED`?

> The TransactionAttribute is not used at all in SecondEjbType or ThirdEjbType... neither at the class nor method level. I understand this to mean that secondEjb.doSomething() and thirdEjb.doSomething() will both operate within the transaction supplied for firstEjb.doSomething()

This means that the default transaction attribute is used, i.e. `REQUIRED`, and a `REQUIRED` method is guaranteed to be executed within a transaction (the container would start one **if** required).

So in your case, `secondEjb.doSomething()` and `thirdEjb.doSomething()` should be indeed executed within the transaction of `firstEjb.doSomething()`.

> have I missed something obvious, or is my conceptual understanding basically correct and the issue may lie elsewhere?

The rule of thumb for (transaction-scoped) persistence context propagation is that the persistence context propagates as the JTA transaction propagates. But there are some restrictions. The JPA specification puts it like this:

> #### 5.6.3 Persistence Context Propagation
>
> As described in section 5.1, a single
>   persistence context may correspond to
>   one or more JTA entity manager
>   instances (all associated with the
>   same entity manager factory).
>
> The persistence context is propagated
>   across the entity manager instances as
>   the JTA transaction is propagated.
>
> Propagation of persistence contexts
>   only applies within a **local**
>   environment. Persistence contexts are
>   not propagated to remote tiers.

And Sahoo (from the GlassFish team) writes more explicitly about the propagation rules in [Persistence Context propagation](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/10/27/persistence-context-propagation):

> 3. (rule #3) Don't expect PC to be propagated when you call a remote EJB even when the remote EJB happens to be running in the same JVM or part of the same application.

So, assuming you're using JPA everywhere, I would expect business methods called within the same transaction to inherit the same persistence context only **if you aren't using `Remote` interfaces** (I don't know if this is a GlassFish specific interpretation of the spec but Sahoo is pretty clear about this restriction).

PS: JPA assumes a `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level (so optimistic locking can work) and standard JPA does not allow custom settings of isolation levels (well, some providers do allow to change it either globally or per request but that's non portable).

PPS: *I*'m not convinced isolation levels are the key to your problem here.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 5.6.3 "Persistence Context Propagation"

Comment: +1 Excellent point on the Remote interface.  Remote interface calls are not guaranteed to happen in the same thread, if not that breaks propagation right there.  Second, any arguments passed in or returned will always be serialized and that will cause JPA entities to detach if they are passed through remote interfaces.

Comment: @David Blevins:  I don't THINK this has any bearing on me, as I'm using Local interfaces only for `SecondEjbType` and `ThirdEjbType`.  However, I am using a Remote interface for the `FirstEjbType` entry point.  You asked why it uses the `TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY` annotation... and it's because this entry point is intended to be called only by remote EJB clients that are managing their own transaction (I wasn't the original author of all this).  Either way, thanks for the info... I had no idea about this distinction between Local and Remote.

Comment: It's the most helpful answer for me. Pascal, you are a Golden Man! I injected EJBs locally using remote interfaces and could not understand the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Since [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa) is mentioned in the tags, I guess that persistence context is not flushed before calling `thirdEjb` methods, so changes are not written to the database.

By default, JPA persistence context is flushed before commit, before execution of a JPA query or manually with `em.flush()`. So, visibility of changes depends on the data access method used in `thirdEjb` - if data are read, for example, using JDBC, changes shouldn't be visible without `em.flush()`.

Comment: Excellent point!  However, we are in fact calling `em.flush()` after the database write in the first method.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide more information to get this question answered.

- Are you running in a Java EE container?
- Have you set a non-standard flush mode?
- Can you post your persistence.xml file?

Be aware that 'persistence context' and transaction lifecycle may not be the same.

*Transactions*

Per EJB 3.0 the default transaction attribute for all EJB 3.0 applications is `REQUIRED`. The doc's for transaction type are here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html

Are you perhaps using the `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction type which will operate in a separate transaction?

**In particular, try using a local rather than remote interface for the 2nd and 3rd EJBs**.

*Flushing*

With default settings a flush is forced before a query (if needed) to ensure results are correct: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html

Try calling `entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);` to make sure a flush happens before your query. Enable SQL logging in your JPA provider to be sure that the updates / inserts are really being sent to the DB prior to the select.

Comment: I updated the question above to reflect the three bullet-points you asked about.  We are not using `REQUIRES_NEW` anywhere.