# One session design pattern for EJB JPA and GWT RequestFactory aka keeping JPA session between multiple method calls

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, ejb, requestfactory

The setup is like this:

**Front-end:**  `GWT` using `RequestFactory` for sending data objects
**Back-end:**
*Web-layer:*
   `GWT` server side code which has injected EJB
*EJB-layer:*
Stateless sesion beans:

**Data access bean** (`DAB`)=> has injected `EntityManager` for `JPA` operations and provides methods for merging and retrieving of entities
**Facade bean** (`FB`) => calls methods of DAB and is interface between EJB and web layer

When an entity object (lets say `MyEntity`) is to be saved after it has been modified at the client side, the flow is like this:
1. Initiated by the client
2. Server side `GWT` code is run and invokes the following methods:
3. The `find()` method looks up the instance of `MyEntity` using `FB.findMyEntity()` which calls `DAB.findMyEntity()` which in turn uses `EntityManager` to do the look-up. The `find()` method must be invoked as its part of `RequestFactory` flow in `GWT`.
4. The `save()` leads to `FB.saveMyEntity()` --> `DAB.saveMyEntity()` --> `EntityManager.merge()` and the changed entity object is persisted.

It is obvious that each of `find()` and `save()` methods run in  different `JPA` transaction which is ineffective and bad design.

With regards to keeping the facade bean interface with simple look-up and saving methods:

1. What is the best design to handle this situation? - preferably with having both method calls in one `JPA` transaction.
2. What are alternatives? With pros and cons.

EDIT: Including simplified examples of the code for `FB` and `DAB`.

Facade bean (`FB`):

```
            @Stateless
            public class MyFacadeBean implements MyFacade{

                @EJB
                private DataAccessBean dab;

                @Override
                public void saveMyEntity(MyEntity entity) {
                    dab.saveMyEntity(entity);
                }

                @Override
                public void findMyEntity(int id) {
                    dab.saveMyEntity(id);
                }

            }
```

Data access bean (`DAB`):

```
        @Stateless
        public class DataAccesseBean implements DataAccessBeanInterface{

            @PersistenceContext
            private EntityManager entityManager;

            @Override
            public void saveMyEntity(MyEntity entity) {
                entityManager.merge(entity);
            }

            @Override
            public void findMyEntity(int id) {
                entityManager.find(MyEntity.class,id);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please post the code of FB and DAB, at least the annotations, fields, and methods which are involved in your question.

Comment: Is `@EJB` the correct annotation for `entityManager`?

Comment: You are right. It was a mistake. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: You **should** use separate transactions, but you **must** run them in the same JPA session (same `EntityManager` instance, one per HTTP request) so that you have a single instance per entity.

Answer (score 1):

In your web layer you have *two* calls to a *stateless session bean*, so this results in *two* transactions.

There are three options

---

- Use a **`UserTransaction`** in your web layer code:

```java
final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
final UserTransaction ut = (UserTransaction) ic.lookup("UserTransaction");
ut.begin();
try {
    // find
    // set new value in entity
    // save
    ut.commit();
    System.out.println("committed");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ut.rollback();
    System.out.println("rolled back");
}
```

1. This way the **client** controls the transaction.
2. If someone forgets to use a `UserTransaction`, this will result in multiple transactions.
3. There is no need to change the EJB side.

---

- Add a method in the facade which calls **both** DAB methods on behalf of the client:

```java
public void findAndSave(int id, String newValue, ...) {
  // find
  // set new value in entity
  // save
}
```

1. This way the **EJB** controls the transaction.
2. The facade simplifies the interface (*n* calls are reduced to *1*)
3. You possibly have to provide other methods as well on the EJB side. `findAndSave` is close to the *database*. I suggest using methods/names which correspond to the *use case* like `updatePersonAddress` for example.

---

- Convert your facade into a **stateful session bean**

A quote from [Enterprise Java Beans, 2nd edition,](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/ebeans/ch08_05.htm) :

> 8.5.1. Transaction Propagation in Bean-Managed Transactions
>
> With stateless session beans ... transactions that are managed using the UserTransaction must be started and completed within the same method ... In other words, UserTransaction transactions cannot be started in one method and ended in another.
> ...
> With stateful session beans, however, a transaction can begin in one method and be committed in another because a stateful session bean is only used by one client. This allows a stateful session bean to associate itself with a transaction across several different client-invoked methods.

1. You have to use a **stateful session bean**
2. You have to use **bean managed transacations**
3. Transaction control is spread over both **client and EJB**
4. `begin` and `commit` are in different methods.

---

Experience told me that the 1st approach does not work, if performance matters.

So personally I prefer the 2nd approach: The control on the duration/scope of transactions is on the EJB side; the same applies to the number of SQL statements which hit the database. Clients only call one single method of the service/facade (for a single HTTP request for example).

Notes:

- I have tested this setup using JBoss 6.1.1 with PostgreSql.
- The only reliable way to double-check the number of transactions was to observe the PostgreSql log file.

Related:

- [Why do EJB beans with bean-managed transactions act as a “transacation barrier”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17898154/2390083)
- [Transaction propagation from BMT into CMT bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8443769/2390083)
- [How to propagate a client-side UserTransaction into a stateless session bean using BMT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893144/2390083)
- [Persistence context propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147210/2390083)

Comment: My problem here is that I cannot control the call to find() method. I only provide the method implementation. The same applies for save() method => So the `findAndSave()` method is not an option. Both methods are also part (at current design) of two different objects in web layer. GWT RequestFactory framework code controls the calls to this methods. According to your answer the solution (even if not ideal one) could be to:

Comment: 1. Obtain custom transaction in `find()` method and begin it. 2. "Store it"/provide access to the transaction instance to the second object which invokes `save()` 3. In the `save()` method use this transaction and commiting it at the end. Is that correct?

Comment: @LeNoob That's actually a 3rd option, using a SFSB. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Actually I meant, getting the transaction instance from facade stateless bean to web layer servlet/dao object. Is that even possible in EJB? Using stateful session bean occured to me as the possible solution but I was not sure if it is the best or only solution. Based on what you mentioned, it actually seems to be THE BEST way to go - stateful session bean which commits transaction at the end of the session.

Comment: You mean explicitly "passing/exporting/returning/storing" a transaction context? A transaction context is propagated implicitly, it's possibly injected into SBs, and it's normally bound to a thread. In **your specific case** each approach has it's pros and cons. Try to implement the SFSB for a simple use case, and please report your result (nevertheless I suggest implementing the other options as well).